# CSS - a tag width and height in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, height, width

I have the following code which works fine in all browsers other than IE.

```
<div class="hovertest">
    <img src="myimage.jpg" width="200" height="100" alt="myimage" />
    <a href="link.html">&nbsp;</a>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div class="test">test2</div>
```

jquery:

```
$("a").hover( function () {
    $(".test").fadeOut();
});
```

css:

```
div {
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#B22;
    position:relative;
}

a {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

The a tag is not spanning 100% width and height of the div. The odd thing is though, by removing the image from the div and only having the a tag in there, it works fine in all browsers including IE.

Does anyone know what might be happening to the a tag when there's an image in the div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

```
$("a, img").hover( function () {
    $(".test").fadeOut();
});
```

DEMO: 
http://jsfiddle.net/a4GAW/3/

**Update:**

If you click the img, you can use this workaround

```
$("img").click(function(){
    document.location = $(this).next("a").attr("href");
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/a4GAW/5/

Comment: See where you're coming from, but the link needs to actually be a link too... perhaps # was a bad example... I'll change!

Comment: Good thinking, I was trying to work this out without using a workaround but I think I might have to.

Comment: Indeed it is better, but yeah IE just won't always work as you expect to.

Answer (score 2):

Use `display:block` and `left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0` for 100% width and height.
See this http://jsfiddle.net/fliptheweb/RESTy/

Comment: Thats very fun IE bug with `background-color`. If i add `background-color` to link - all works perfect in ie :) Check http://jsfiddle.net/fliptheweb/RESTy/ again plz

Comment: Yeah, I'd noticed that, but adding a background-color will cover the image! Though your opacity change covers that I guess. IE clearly goes out of its way to make life difficult!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the position declarations and use the image as a background for the anchor.

```
a {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display: block;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-image: url(myimage.jpg);
}
```

An anchor is an inline element, it will not accept height and width as is. Givingit a position effectively sets it to a block element, but it may have other effects too. Try this, see what happens :)